# Notepad++ How to remove a lines containing 3 same characters in order

Tags: regex, notepad++

lemme show an example. My file looks like this:

```
AaaAab
AacAaa
AacAap
AaaBbb
```

I would like to delete all the lines which contains 3 same characters in first or second 3 chars. Which means I will receive only `AacAap` from above example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
^(?:(.)\1\1.*|.{3}(.)\2\2.*)$
```

Put that in the "Find what" field, and put an empty string in the "Replace with" field.

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HsPugj/2).

Comment: This doesn't delete the lines.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:(.)\1\1|...(.)\2\2).*\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginning of line
(?:     : start non capture group
  (.)   : group 1, any character but newline
  \1\1  : same as group 1, twice
 |      : OR
  ...   : 3 any character
  (.)   : group 2, any character but newline
  \2\2  : same as group 2, twice
)       : end group
.*      : 0 or more any character
\R      : any kind of linebreak
```

**Result for given example:**

```
AacAap
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
^(?:...)?(.)\1\1.*\r?\n?
```

The part `(.)\1\1` matches three consecutive same characters with a capture and two backreferences. `(?:...)?` makes the three first characters optional, this way the consecutive characters can be at the beginning of the line or at the 4th position.

`.*\r?\n?` is only here to match all remaining characters of the line including the line break *(you can preserve line breaks if you want, you only have to remove `\r?\n?`)*.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the next regex `(?im)^(?:...)?(.)\1\1.*(?:\R|\z)`.

To try the regex online and get an explanation, please click [here](https://regex101.com/r/bZNQhq/1).